# AWS CDK - S3 to Lambda: creation of the S3EventSource with bucket returning `Property '_resource' is missing in type` error

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I am trying to create a cdk stack to trigger a lambda after a `s3:ObjectCreated:Put` event on S3.

I am following some tutorials (like this [one](https://dev.to/aws-builders/how-to-trigger-an-aws-lambda-from-s3-events-53c3)), but I am not able to make the creation of the event source `S3EventSource` works, I am receiving a Typescript error when I am trying to add the bucket property to the event source:

```
const s3PutEventSource = new S3EventSource(bucket, {
  events: [
    s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED_PUT
  ]
});
```

Currently I am receiving the following error on my IDE and also when I try to run the `npm run cdk deploy` command:

```
lib/cdk-s3-stack.ts:29:48 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'import("/Users/jeprandini/cdk-s3/src/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-s3/lib/bucket").Bucket' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("/Users/jeprandini/cdk-s3/src/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-ec2/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-s3/lib/bucket").Bucket'.
Property '_resource' is missing in type 'import("/Users/jeprandini/cdk-s3/src/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-s3/lib/bucket").Bucket' but required in type 'import("/Users/jeprandini/cdk-s3/src/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-ec2/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-s3/lib/bucket").Bucket'.

29     const s3PutEventSource = new S3EventSource(bucket, {
                                                ~~~~~~

node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-ec2/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-s3/lib/bucket.d.ts:1489:22
    1489     private readonly _resource;
                            ~~~~~~~~~
    '_resource' is declared here.

Subprocess exited with error 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! s3-to-lambda-cdk@0.1.0 cdk: `cdk "deploy"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the s3-to-lambda-cdk@0.1.0 cdk script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jeprandini/.npm/_logs/2021-11-09T20_53_14_772Z-debug.log
```

My stack code:

```
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import * as s3 from '@aws-cdk/aws-s3';
import { NodejsFunction } from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-nodejs';
import { S3EventSource} from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-event-sources';

export class S3ToLambdaCdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
 constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
  super(scope, id, props);

const BUCKET_NAME = 'demo-bucket'

// S3 bucket
const bucket = new s3.Bucket(this, BUCKET_NAME, {
  /**
   * The following properties ensure the bucket is properly 
   * deleted when we run cdk destroy */
  autoDeleteObjects: true,
  removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY
});

const lambdaReadStream = new NodejsFunction(this, 'readStream', {
  entry: 'lambda-fns/readStream/handler.js',
  handler: 'handler'
});


const s3eventSource = new S3EventSource(bucket, {
  events: [
    s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED_PUT
  ]
});

lambdaReadStream.addEventSource(s3eventSource);

// Outputs
new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'BucketArn', { value: bucket.bucketArn });
new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'LambdaFunctionArn', { value: lambdaReadStream.functionArn });
 }
}
```

my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "cdk-s3",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "bin": {
    "cdk-s3": "bin/cdk-s3.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "test": "jest",
    "cdk": "cdk"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/assert": "1.116.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.10",
    "@types/node": "10.17.27",
    "aws-cdk": "^1.127.0",
    "jest": "^26.4.2",
    "ts-jest": "^26.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda": "^1.95.1",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-s3": "1.95.1",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-event-sources": "^1.127.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-nodejs": "^1.127.0",
    "@aws-cdk/core": "^1.127.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are having some dependencies conflicts in your `cdk` imports, for some dependencies you are using the version `1.127.0` and for others you are using the version `1.95.1` for example the `@aws-cdk/aws-s3` library.

Normally you need to use the same version for all your cdk modules. Try to use the version `ˆ1.95.1` for all of your CDK modules.

To to this, change the cdk dependencies to the version `ˆ1.95.1`, use the command `rm -rf node_modules` to delete your `node_modules` directory and run the `npm i` to recreate the `node_modules` dir and to install your modules again.

After that you able to run the command `npm run cdk deploy` without issues.

Comment: Thanks! this helped me a lot, I did not find what I was doing wrong